# Understanding command ls .*

Tags: command-line, ls

I found that command `ls .*` shows all files and folders in upper directory. It is the same like I do

```
cd .. 
ls *
```

But how this achieved with one command `ls .*`? What is the meaning of `.` and `*` in this combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot `.` gets expanded to `..` by applying wildcard (`*`), as you know single dot `.` represents the current directory while double dot `..` shows the parent directory.

So by doing `ls .*`, you are actually doing.

```
ls .
```

and

```
ls ..
```

Which list files on the current directory and parent directory. (CMIIW)

Comment: It will list `.files` too.

Comment: +1 @bac0n, worth to also mention for beginners, that files with names beginning with dot are 'hidden' but rather easy to find ;-)

Comment: It will also list `.subdirectory/`